# How can I listen message from background.js of Chrome Extension in Angular web application?

Tags: angular, google-chrome-extension

I have a Chrome Extension that sends an message to all tab (at background.js) like this:

```
    chrome.tabs.query({}).then((tabs)=> {
        if (tabs) {
            tabs.forEach(tab => {
                chrome.tabs.sendMessage(tab.id, msg);
            });
        }
    });
```

So how can I listen the message in my Angular web app like content.js?**
I need that because i need to store msg.value to LocalStorage of Angular web app

That like my content.js in extension code below:

```
chrome.runtime.onMessage.addListener((msg, sender, response) => {
    //handle message here
}
```

I need it on my Angular web app!
Thank you very much!

Answer (score 0):

Only scripts or scripts injected into a webpage can communicate with the rest of your extension.

What you can do is inject content scripts into your web app. Then use that script to do your logic. If you need to work with states in your app, make those states global so that your content script can access it.